# Dúvida na logica do cadastramento com codeigniter!

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Tenho uma “tabela” com os seguintes campos:
pessoa_id, 
área_id,
datainicio (Default),
datafim (Default),

Minha duvida na lógica é o seguinte:

Cadastro um funcionário e sua área de responsabilidade com a data inicio. Quando ao efetuar novamente o cadastro com um novo funcionário referente à área que já possui um responsável, automaticamente é preenchido por default a data fim do antigo responsável e crie uma nova data de início com o novo responsável referente aquela área sem a data fim. Na verdade, estou tentando fazer um histórico referente aos funcionários responsáveis por determinadas áreas, com sua data de início e fim.

Como devo proceder na lógica?

```
public function cadastrar(){
    esta_logado();
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('pessoa', 'FUNCIÓANARIO', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('area', 'ÁREA', 'trim|required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE):
    $dados['pessoa_id'] = $this->input->post('pessoa', TRUE);
    $dados['area_id'] = $this->input->post('area', TRUE);
    $this->responsavel->do_insert($dados);

    endif;


    set_tema('titulo', 'Cadastrar responsável');
    set_tema('conteudo', load_modulo('responsavel', 'cadastrar'));
    load_template();    
}
```

A lógica deveria ser feito nesse controller! essa função está cadastrando no banco!

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi ao certo se você deseja uma lógica para o Codeigniter ou uma função qualquer que possa realizar isto.

Se pensarmos em banco de dados o que você pode fazer é uma consulta retornando o ID do registro que possui esta informação, caso exista você realizar um update no mesmo definindo a data de inicio e depois realiza a inserção do novo registro.

Existe a possibilidade de realizar isto através de uma única instrução de insert, criando uma trigger que pode ser acionada a qualquer insert realizado no sistema para esta tabela, atualizando o registro anterior com a data de término da ação.

Vejo mais uma instrução SQL a ser realizada do que realmente um método criado em uma classe específica para isto, onde talvez consumiria mais recursos do sistema.

Passe mais informações, por exemplo que banco utiliza, se pode ou não existir um registro de responsável no sistema quando da inserção de um novo, etc. assim posso tentar criar algum código que te ajude.

Espero ter ajudado e dado uma idéia de como pode ser feito

Abs

Comment: O banco de dados é o mysql, a lógica seria para o Codeigniter. Já tenho um registro no banco de dados, com o funcionário responsável por uma área. Quando eu cadastrar um novo funcionário referente alguma área que já possui um responsável cadastrado, seja preenchida a data fim do antigo funcionário responsável e cria - se um novo registro, com o novo funcionário responsável pela área e a data de início. Pela lógica a data fim do antigo funcionário e a data início do novo funcionário. Desculpa qualquer coisa se minha lógica não está sendo clara!

Answer (score 0):

Você quer que o novo usuário cadastrado receba a data de início (mas não a de fim), e a data de fim do último usuário inserido na tabela, receba a data equivalente  a que seria de início do novo usuário? OK.

Se for isso, antes de você inserir o novo usuário no banco de dados  (tabela), você precisa pegar e editar o último usuário inserido na   sua tabela, no meu exemplo, usarei a tabela chamada **tb_users**.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tb_users); // essa é a query.
```

OBS: A tabela precisa ter um ID **único** crescente, caso contrário, várias linhas serão retornadas na query e não farão o que você deseja. Provavelmente sua tabela é em ordem crescente de ID, seria mais lógico para o seu problema, então estaria tudo bem até aqui.

Após pegar o ID do ultimo usuário, você então pode fazer um simples update naquela linha. Irei apresentar um pseudocode, já que não sabemos como são feitos seus inserts, reads, updates e deletes, no caso, você adeque a lógica.

```
$ultimo_usuario = carregarUsuario(id_da_ultima_linha_da_tabela); // último inserido
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); // apenas setando a data
$ultimo_usuario->datadefim = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // data e hora atual da minha região
$ultimo_usuario->update(); // update, atualizar a linha no baco.

// novo usário, instancie e adicione os dados necessários. Só irei mostras a data
$novo_usuario = new Usuario();
$novo_usuario->datadeinicio = $ultimo_usuario->datadefim; // data de inicio do novo, é a data fim do antigo, certo?
$novo_usuario->save(); // insert, inserir linha no banco.
```

Caso você não possua **ID** único na tabela, para fazer a query, você irá precisar guardar a informação (id) do último usuário inserido, em algum lugar.